# react js only the last checkbox's state is set?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I want to check my checkboxes according to the data I get from fetch api in my react js app. I'm using the code example from [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-work-with-multiple-checkboxes-in-react/) in my project like this:

```
const listHari = [
  { nama: 'senin', nomor: 1 },
  { nama: 'selasa', nomor: 2 },
  { nama: 'rabu', nomor: 3 },
  { nama: 'kamis', nomor: 4 },
  { nama: 'jumat', nomor: 5 },
  { nama: 'sabtu', nomor: 6 },
  { nama: 'minggu', nomor: 7 },
];

const AddRute = () => {
  const [pilihHari, setPilihHari] = useState([]);

  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    new Array(listHari.length).fill(false)
  );

  const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );

    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);

    let selected = [];
    updatedCheckedState.map((item, index) => {
      // console.log('updated', item, index, listHari[index].nomor);
      if (item) {
        selected.push(listHari[index].nomor);
      }
    });

    setPilihHari(selected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRuteById();
  }, []);

  const getRuteById = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/mrute/${id}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    /*
    data result looks like this
    [
      {id: "1", nama: "senin", hari: "1"}, 
      {id: "2", nama: "selasa", hari: "2"}, 
      {id: "3", nama: "rabu", hari: "3"},
      {id: "4", nama: "kamis", hari: "4"}, 
      {id: "5", nama: "jumat", hari: "5"}
    ]
    */

    data.map((item) => {
      handleOnChange(item.hari-1);
    });
  }
}
```

but only the fifth checkboxes gets checked. what is wrong with the code? any help is appreciated

Comment: This looks overly complex and unnecessary for what you're trying to accomplish. Have you thought about adding an additional 'isChecked' property to the objects in your list?

Comment: but the `checkedState` is already just an array of boolean values, which I put in my `<input type="checkbox" checked={checkedState[index]} />`

Comment: Why can't you just toggle them all true in your get function `setCheckedState(new Array(data.length).fill(true))` instead of calling handleOnChange multiple times?

Comment: won't that set *all* the checkboxes as true (checked) ? I need to make it so that only some of the checkboxes are checked based on the data I get from fetch api.. also, the number in the `hari` property isn't always sequential. it can be 1,2,3, but it can also be 2,4,5

Answer (score 0):

It works OK for me can you share your html

[CodeSandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/50hofy)

Comment: this is my sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-dirac-0dlt8z?file=/src/App.js and it only checks the 5th checkbox like this https://ibb.co/Khg8SyB

Comment: @dapidmini because setState is an async task you were trying to get checkedStates before they are updated. I added another function to fire only after fetching to assign the checkbox status according to fetched data. It should work now   [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mendel-k669el)